# Ruby On Rails CMS inspired by DjangoCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, django-cms

I need to choose and customize a Ruby CMS (based on Ruby On Rails preferably) for a couple of pretty large web sites. I know `Radiant CMS`, `Refinery CMS`, and `Locomotive` are the most famous CMS in rails, but none of them include all the features I need. Here are the main non trivial features that are (sometimes) missing in those CMS :

---

- **Page main content** : Each page main content (each menu item) can display :

  - A list of articles of a "category" (like a blog)
  - An individual article extracted from a category
  - An individual page created with a WYSIMYM editor (this is the basic functionality of RefineryCMS for instance)
  - Links (external or internal resources in the library, like an uploaded document)
  - Custom page that require specific development (subscriptions forms,... classic rails controllers)

---

- **Template management** :

  - I should be able to reuse "templates" across multiple pages. For instance, a template could be a layout that have a couple of "Placeholders", like one "main placeholder" (that will contains the main content of a page), and a "sidebar placeholder". When an admin build a new page in the admin interface, he should be able to select the template he will use.
  - The placeholders of a template, just like a page, are editable in the admin (ex: the content of the sidebard). All the pages that use this template get updated of course.

RQ : This template / placeholder feature exists partialy in [DjangoCMS](https://www.django-cms.org/)

---

- **"Plugins"** : the content of the placeholders should be filled with custom plugins that I can reuse on multiple templates. For instance, I could code a Twitter plugin that displays the last 10 tweets from a user (a parameter of the plugin). So in the template edit page, I could add this plugin inside the "side placeholder".

This notion of plugin exists for instance in [DjangoCMS](https://www.django-cms.org/)

---

- **WYSIWYM / WYSIWYG editor** : in the content of an article or a page created with the WYSIWYM editor, I should be able to

  - Insert a link to a internal resource form the librairy, for instance a PDF document uploaded previously
  - Insert internal images form the internal librairy
  - Insert slide shows of images
  - Insert videos from Youtube

---

- **Multisite** : ressources like a list of articles (a categorie of articles), documents, can be displayed on pages of different sites on different domains. Everythings is managed from a simple admin site

---

- **Multilingual** (articles / pages can be translated)

---

What would be your choice and why ?

Should I rebuild a custom solution from scratch ?

Did anybody implement one of those features (in `Radiant CMS`, `Refinery CMS`, or `Locomotive` for instance) ?

Thanks for any help or advice on this !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you give [ComfortableMexicanSofa](https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa) a try. While it may not have every single feature you want, integrating those are pretty trivial.

I'd say there's no CMS with better templating capabilities than Sofa.

Plugins, helpers, partials, snippets... whatever you want to call them can be inserted anywhere.

This CMS comes with Wymeditor for richtext editing. It's not fully integrated yet, so it's not super user-friendly in terms of attaching existing files but I'm working on improving it.

Multisite. Yes, sites can also be attached to a locale. So you can have http://en.example.com and http://fr.example.com

There's also a [Wiki](https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki) that may answer some of your questions.

I'm the author btw. Feel free to ask anything.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know this CMS Engine, I'll give it a try